# How to see which element was clicked first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selection menu using `toggleClass().` to see which menu options were selected:

```
$('.img1, .img2, .text1, .tex2').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

The way my selection menu works is that if two elements have the class `selected` then something will happen. For example:

```
if ( $('.img1').hasClass('selected') && ('.text1').hasClass('selected') ) {
    // do something
}
```

This all works perfectly however I want to disable the user from picking two `imgs` or two `texts`. The way I want to do this is just have the first selected element be removed from the selected class and the second selected element stay selected. For example:

```
if ( $('.img1').hasClass('selected') && ('.img2').hasClass('selected') ) {
        // remove selected from the element that was first clicked and keep selected on the element that was clicked second
}
```

What would be the best way of achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was asking about the DV on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.img1, .img2').click(function() {
    $('.img1, .img2').removeClass('selected').filter(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
$('.text1, .text2').click(function() {
     $('.text1, .text2').removeClass('selected').filter(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Separating your click events will ensure only one of each type of item is selected.

Also, make sure you aren't doing `$('this')`.

It should be `$(this)`.

Comment: @Ferri Did you try it with that latest code, the `.filter(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

This will add the class name "first" to the first item that is clicked. The rest is up to you.

```
$('.img1, .img2, .text1, .tex2').click(function() {
    $('this').toggleClass('selected');
    if($('.first').length==0) {
        $('this').addClass('first');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps if you had an array that kept track of the id of the clicked items, you could use that:

```
var clickArr = new Array();
$('.img1, .img2, .text1, .tex2').click(function()
{
    $('this').toggleClass('selected');
    clickArr.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

then, when you find a spot where both are selected:

```
if ( $('.img1').hasClass('selected') && ('.img2').hasClass('selected') )
{
    $("#"+clickArr[0]).removeClass("selected");
    clickArr.shift();
}
```

This could be tricky because you will have to empty the array every time you "process a selection" that is valid.  But maybe this can get you started.